# calculate averages of multiple values in java

Tags: java, list, average

I have a list which looks like this:

```
40   4.8980713
5   4.8012613
5   4.8980713
46   4.8980713
5   4.8980713
5   4.8945613
40   4.0120713
5   4.8980713
5   4.8828129
5   4.8000713
40   4.8947213
5   4.8980713
46   4.8980713
5   4.8828125
46   4.8980713
```

This is a snapshot of a much larger list that contains values of nodes and their arrival times. I need to find the average of arrival time in right column for each node in the left column.

I'm not sure how to approach this in Java using Lists.

Comment: How would you do it in another language (or manually with pen and paper)?

Comment: is this a list from a file?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  Loop through the array list for each row. Add the values of time for each node and create a counter everytime the node is encountered, or create new counter of new node value. Finally, divide the Sum of all time with the counter for each node.

Comment: @iambdot   Yes this is a list from a csv

Comment: You can calculate the average time as you parse the CSV file, there's no need to involve Java Lists at all. Unless you need to manipulate that list later for another purpose.

Comment: @Milack OK! I'll try that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first read the CSV file to a `List<String>`. Then parse it by splitting it on the triple spaces. Then collect it to a `Map<Integer, Double>` where the keys are your nodes and the values are the average. You can use the `averagingDouble` from `Collectors`.

Code then looks like this:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/arrivals.csv"));

Map<Integer, Double> averages = lines.stream()
                                     .map(s -> s.split("   "))
                                     .collect(
                                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                           r -> Integer.parseInt(r[0]),
                                           Collectors.averagingDouble(v -> Double.parseDouble(v[1]))
                                        )
                                     );
```

If you run this for your example you get:

```
{5=4.872644944444445, 40=4.6016213, 46=4.8980713}
```

Comment: Thanks!!  So it this what you're trying to do: 1. reading file into stream 2. Splitting each stream by \t 3. collecting individual node values along with time (again collected with average)

Comment: Glad to help. That is indeed what the code does. It's not really _trying_, it's actually working code; I wrote a unit test and the output of your example is also provided in the answer. Note that \t is tab, the example in the question doesn't use tabs but uses 3 spaces.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying. I couldn't have come up with this concise code so quickly. I have certainly learnt something new today.